# How Marshal.FreeHGlobal can free unmanned array?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanaged-memory

I have reserved an unmanned array using:

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(array[0]) * array.Length);
```

then free it using:

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr );
```

as far as I read, this will free the memory correctly and no memory leak gonna happen. 
My question: is this true? if it is, how that works? is the Marshal state-full and store meta-data about every reserved data?

Comment: One of way to track allocation size is to prefix allocated block with size, like BSTR do that.

Comment: You meant that this is happening in the allocation and freeing automatically and every thing goes smoothly and nicely  ??

Comment: I say, it is one of multiple ways to do that. I does not know how it actually implemented. As @thefiloe say, this functions just a wrapper around WinAPI functions. The contract is, that `FreeHGlobal` should correctly free anything that allocated by `AllocHGlobal`.

Comment: Satisfied answer many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AllocHGlobal` method exposes the `LocalAlloc` function. And the `FreeHGlobal` Method exposes the `LocalFree` function. The memory management is not being done by any managed component. It is done by the code behind these windows api functions.

To answer your question: Yes it has to keep track of the allocated size. You can retrieve the size of a handle by calling `LocalSize` function. To be honest, I don't know how its being done internally, but you don't need to know that.

Comment: So May you please just relate it to my question in more clear way if you do not mind